# Oracle APEX 5.1 connect to remote db using JDBC and query data

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-apex

I have only used db links to get access to remote db so far. Now I have to find a way to use JDBC to connect to remote db and get data. Can someone guide me what all things would I need to ask the remote db admin in order to setup a jdbc connection, and once I have the connection, how do I query the database using java stored procedure, just like I am querying it over remote db right now with db link? Is there a good quick start or a tutorial out there that I can use?

Comment: Why do you think the remote DBA needs to set up something special if you connect via JDBC? Is there a special requirement that you use JDBC? If you  are more comfortable with DB links, you can use them with APEX, too

Comment: I basically want to confirm what are the requirements for JDBC connection. Yes I am using DB links right now, but we need to move to JDBC connection now due to some other factors. I am completely new to using JDBC, so trying to find some pointers for a kickstart.

Comment: For the JDBC connection you only need the service name, port and hostname, there are no special settings on the remote site. For using a JDBC connection with APEX I can't really help you there. The only connection of JAVA and APEX I saw as a DBA was in a very old 3.2 installation and there JAVA was accessed as a DB JAVA package.

Comment: Embedding Java in the database: http://www.gokhanatil.com/2009/07/how-to-develop-java-stored-procedures.html Still a bad idea, and it has nothing to do with APEX. *we need to move to JDBC connection now due to some other factors* - I hardly think so.